# Best practise: where to put hard coded value? Front-end vs Backend?

Tags: frontend, backend

For web service, sometimes we are pulling some data from database and it needs some minor tweaking(eg. DB: UTC-09:00 -> frontend: (UTC-09:00) Alaska). I was wondering where is a good place to put the two-way mapping? Front-end vs Back-end?

It feels easier to do it in the front-end as we can put tags to replace the content during the page rendering and when the data is being sent back, the backend data is intact and can be directly consumed by database. In the above example we are basically providing a drop down list for user to choose from. We want to add countries to the time zone offset while still keeping the original format in the database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is always better to do formating in the frontend, that way you will always have a reference to the object itself, and you won't need to parse it again.